# run unix shell script which is situated on server and maped as a U:// dirver on windows from windows in java application?

Tags: java, windows, shell, unix

**When i run  `runShellScript(unixCommand);` i get following error: `sh.exe has stoped working.`
Can anyone tell what is the problem and how to solve it?**

```
#!/bin/sh
# this assumes webserver is running on port 8080
echo "Deploy everything first"
echo "These next 3 should work..."
echo "The rest of these should fail... (nicely of course)"
echo "This should work but print debug info on the client and server"
# Now undeploy everything

String unixCommand = "sh U:\\home\\ash\\test.sh";
            try {
                runShellScript(unixCommand);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }



 public static void runShellScript(String unixCommand) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", unixCommand);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process shellProcess = processBuilder.start();
    InputStream inputStream = shellProcess.getInputStream();
    int consoleDisplay;
    while ((consoleDisplay = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.println(consoleDisplay);
    }
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's just wicked. There are some issues with mapped drives, even with plain windows command line interpreter - `cmd.exe`. The path expansion doesn't work very well, and also folder identification is a bit crippled. I would be highly surprised if this mix would ever work. One thing you didn't mention - are you using Cygwin on the machine? If yes -- have you tried to run the script manually?

Comment: i do not use Cygwin but it is already installed on my pc.yes i run script on unix manualy and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here.

First, it is good that [Rekin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309259/rekin) asked whether you are using Cygwin, because that is highly relevant.  Cygwin handles Windows drives by prepending `cygdrive/`, then the drive name.  It also prefers Unix-style paths.  So you should change your Unix command to:

```
String unixCommand = "sh /cygdrive/u/home/ash/test.sh";
```

That should execute your script successfully.

However you will next see that the output is just numbers instead of any legible text.  That's because in your `runShellScript`, you are using the lowest level `read()` method, and are reading the process output one byte at a time, then printing each byte, each on its own separate line.  At the very least, you should use a higher level stream, like `DataInputStream` - or basically any class with a `read*` method obtaining `Strings` instead of bytes.  Even better, use a `Reader` subclass like `BufferedReader`, since this is the modern approach since JDK 1.1.  Once you do that, you should see the output.

Comment: Again the same problem: `sh.exe has stopped working`. Did you run this on your computer? i'm using win 7.

Comment: I did.  Is the error message in the stack trace?  Can you print the whole stack trace?

Comment: In the stack trace there is no error but error com from windows als following`sh.exe has stopped working.` The path to sh.exe is `U:\BNT\mks\tk\mksnt`

Comment: What is the path to bash.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here.

First, it is good that Rekin asked whether you are using Cygwin, because that is highly relevant. Cygwin handles Windows drives by prepending cygdrive/, then the drive name. It also prefers Unix-style paths. So you should change your Unix command to:

`String unixCommand = "sh /cygdrive/u/home/ash/test.sh";`

That should execute your script successfully.

However you will next see that the output is just numbers instead of any legible text. That's because in your `runShellScript`, you are using the lowest level `read()` method, and are reading the process output one byte at a time, then printing each byte, each on its own separate line. At the very least, you should use a higher level stream, like `DataInputStream` - or basically any class with a `read*`-method obtaining `Strings` instead of `bytes`. Even better, use a `Reader` subclass like `BufferedReader`, since this is the modern approach since JDK 1.1. Once you do that, you should see the output.